# Create Contact Groups and save in the Application only

Tags: android

in my project create contact groups and add contacts to particular group, these contact groups not visible in main contacts, suppose user delete the contact or group then it should not effect on the main contacts.
anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQLite` database for it and you can store these contacts for your application only. A tutorial can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) how to use `SQLite` database.